# Spacemacs: move cursor back to code after bringing up docs

Tags: clojure, spacemacs

In Spacemacs with the Clojure layer, if I do `SPC m h h`, it splits the window with documentation information, and moves the cursor to the new split containing the docs.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will move the cursor back to the top split that contains the code? The typical vim shortcut I use, `C-w k`, doesn't work when the cursor is in the doc split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often, I just read the documentation and press `q` to close documentation window.

If you're using `evil` mode it's also quite easy to move back with `SPC <window_number>`; for me most often `SPC 1`. 
In `emacs` mode, `C-x o` can work too, but it depends on how many windows you have.